# Trying to convert VB.NET code to C code

Tags: c, vb.net

I'm trying to convert a VB.NET code to C code, but there some functions that I can't understand like bitconverter.getbytes()

Can somebody see my code and explain me if I'm doing this code right or I'm totally wrong, please?

VB.NET

```
SetReadFileOffset(NO, MFTCluster * SectperCluster * BytesPerSect)
```

VB.NET

```
Private Sub SetReadFileOffset(ByRef NO As System.Threading.NativeOverlapped, ByRef curBig As Int64)
        Dim lowoffset() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(curBig)
        Dim highoffset As Int32 = BitConverter.ToInt32(lowoffset, 0)
        Dim high As Int32
        Dim lastbytes(3) As Byte
        Array.Copy(lowoffset, 4, lastbytes, 0, 4)
        high = BitConverter.ToInt32(lastbytes, 0)
        NO.OffsetLow = highoffset
        NO.OffsetHigh = high
    End Sub
```

C

```
 setreadfileoffset(overlapped, (sectperclusters * (bytespercluster * MFTCluster)));
```

C

```
long endianhextodec(BYTE *buffers, int offs){

    BYTE tmp[1] = {0};

       if(offs == 0){

        tmp[0] = buffers[0];
        tmp[1] = buffers[1];
        tmp[2] = buffers[2];
        tmp[3] = buffers[3];

        return tmp[3] << 24;
    }
}

void setreadfileoffset(OVERLAPPED overlap, INT64 crbig ){

BYTE *lowoffset = (BYTE*)malloc(sizeof(crbig));
INT32 higoffset = endianhextodec(lowoffset, 0);
INT32 high;
BYTE lastbytes[3];

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int n = 4; n > 0; n--){

        lastbytes[i] = lowoffset[n];
    }
}

high = endianhextodec(lastbytes, 0);
overlap.Offset = higoffset;
overlap.OffsetHigh = high;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
//int64_t curBig = 0x0123456789ABCDEFLL;
int32_t *p = (int32_t *)&curBig;
int32_t highoffset  = p[0];//0x89ABCDEF
int32_t high = p[1];//0x01234567
```